# Prevent column-count from breaking elements' border

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout, column-count

I'm creating a layout using column-count and -webkit-column-count but I found an issue that appears multiple times.

[image]

As you can see from this image, Chrome 45 (not happening in FF) breaks elements' border, which is very strange and quite annoying. This is a bit the code where the break happens (but **I don't know why it is not happening here, only difference are fonts, and absence of Mayers css reset**):

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
form {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
label {
  display: block;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
  margin-top: 0.625em;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
}
label>span:first-child {
  width: 5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h2>CONFIG:</h2>
<form id="pop_values" action="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span>Mobile</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span>Animate</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Frecuency:</span>
    <input type="number">
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Exclusions:</span>
    <input type="text">
  </label>
</form>
```

But it didn't work. Could you give any enlightenment?

Comment: its work your code snippet

Comment: Can we see a live version of this?

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not very clear (without markup) in your question, it seems your form elements (`label`s and `input`s) are not wrapped in their respective containers and are on their own.

You are preventing break on `label`s only, and hence the `input`s are not bound by that rule. This is the reason you are facing that problem.

Best solution would be to wrap your `label-input` sets in their own containing `div`s and apply `break-inside: avoid` on those `div`s.

**Example**:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
form { -webkit-column-count: 2; -moz-column-count: 2; column-count: 2; }

form > div { -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; page-break-inside: avoid; break-inside: avoid-column; }

form label, form input { display: inline-block; margin: 4px 0px; }
form input[type=text] { width: 50%; }
```

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <input id="chk1" type="checkbox" /><label for="chk1">Mobile</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="chk2" type="checkbox" /><label for="chk2">Animated</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="txt1">Input 1:</label><input id="txt1" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="txt2">Input 2:</label><input id="txt2" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="txt3">Input 3:</label><input id="txt3" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="txt4">Input 4:</label><input id="txt4" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="txt5">Input 5:</label><input id="txt5" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="txt6">Input 6:</label><input id="txt6" type="text" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**Fiddle** to see the effect of resizing: *http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/jd7v0n8e/*

*Note: Last style rule in the above example is to prevent overflow of the `input`s when the the available space is less than their default width.*

### Edit:

(*after Op's comment*)

Now that you have provided your markup, this arrangement should also work. As long as you are sure that all `input`s are properly wrapped inside those `label`s.

See this snippet:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; } 
form{
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
label {
    display: block; margin: 2px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
}
input {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label>This: <input type="text" /></label>
    <label>This is long: <input type="text" /></label>
    <label>This: <input type="text" /></label>
    <label>This: <input type="text" /></label>
    <label>This is much longer than before: <input type="text" /></label>
    <label>This: <input type="text" /></label>
    <label>This: <input type="text" /></label>
    <label>This: <input type="text" /></label>
</form>
```

And also this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/38wjpu28/3/

It seems that there must be something else going on in your markup besides what you have shown in your question.

*Note 2: I would recommend going with a wrapping `div` and keeping the `label` and `input` separate. This would allow you greater control in case you need to change the layouts later on. (e.g. when you need to put `label` on top of `input` instead of side by side)*

Comment: I added a sample of the structure of my code. You are right, labels are on their own, but they are styled as block elements.

Comment: @Vandervals: Per your markup that should cause problems unless you have something else going on with your markup or styles. I have updated the answer with a demo snippet and fiddle.

Comment: I don't understand the second example. What is the difference between my own and yours, other than deleting the <span> tags? I've also attempted to exchange the <label>s for <div>s, and the problem is still here.

Comment: @Vandervals: (1) I did not remove `span`s. It was as you posted in your question. See -- http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32477400/2 . You again updated the question to include spans. Anyway, that will not make any difference. (2) I added the example in my answer not to show differences, but to show that it works without problems.

Comment: In my snippet works as well, so i couldn't detect the problem. I've tryed canceling every css rule each at a time, to see if it was `line-height`'s fault or something, or some em's not giving exact px values... but nothing, I don't know how to get those showing here... As long as I'm concerned the markup is the mostly the same...

Comment: @Vandervals: Please wait. Let me have a look at the updated markup of yours. Give me some time here. I wish you are not going to make any more changes to the markup in the question ;)

Comment: No, I won't. Btw, the same page in FF looks good even without the `page-break` rule. It is very strange that it breaks in the border, so I'm starting to think this may be a bug.

Comment: @Vandervals: (1) As per your above comment, yes there are differences in Chrome / FF. (2) Regarding your problem, I suspect it could be because of `margin-top: 0.675em;` on your `label`. Try making it `0.5em` or `0.7em` and it should fix the problem. Alternatively, a margin in `px` will also fix this. (3) As to why this is happening, I am stumped. I am investigating it further. Meanwhile, could you confirm that the problem is fixed by changing the margin on the label?

Comment: No, it doesn't get fixed. I tryed that and also completly removed it and it still happens.

Comment: @Vandervals: Nopes. Not yet.

Comment: Maybe there is an element outside of the form that is pushing the elements down? Or a rule that isn't present in the snippet? Because "config" also doesn't look like the screenshot.